# Different icons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, icons

May be a easily solvable problem but I cant seem to find a solution.

I understand that you need different icon sizes for different devices as explained here ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html )

But how will my app know which one to use? I see in the plist there is another key option called ‘Icon  Files’. I presume I need to use this instead of the normal ‘Icon File'?

Anyone have a dummies explanation?

Comment: Got it. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app does not need to know which icon to use. iOS itself will figure out which icon to take from your listed icon files entry in Info.plist. Just use the naming convention (`Icon@2x.png` for retina, `Icon~ipad.png` for iPad and simple Icon.png for everything else) and you'll be good.

Note that I'm not saying that you should use exactly these file names. Just use appropriate suffixes when naming icon files.